# How to fix Google tokens Expiring after seven days

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

Is there anyway to get a permanent oauth2 token for Google Sheet API or a semi permanent ?

The one I'm using right now expires once every 7 days which is not very helpful.

If not, is there any alternative for an online spreadsheet application that you can connect with python ?

Answer (score 2):

This depends upon what you are doing if you are accessing a sheet that you own personally then you could use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).   Service accounts are preauthorized and will not expire.

If you are access sheets that are owned by your users then you will need to use Oauth2. If you request off line access then you will get what is called a refresh token.  Refresh tokens can be used to request new access tokens when the access token expires.

As you say that the token is expire after seven days implies that you are using an a refresh token currently.  However you have not set your project in google cloud platform to production.  As it is still in testing your refreshtoken will [expire](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) after seven days.

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

## How to switch to production.

Go to [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) for your project

Find the Oauth consent screen on the left.

[image]

Click got to production

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. Could you provide what steps you took to get your project from the "Testing" phase to Production? I submitted last week and my project says "Pending" but my refresh token keeps expiring after 7 days.

Comment: Check my update.  Your project says pending verification probably.  Not pending production.

Comment: Thanks for the response and I posted a screen shot of the verification and publishing status. My token still expired after 7 days... Any suggestions here?

Comment: You will need to start the verification process.

Comment: Note that if your app only accesses non restricted scopes (for example if it can only access the google drive documents it itself created) you won't need to verify if you publish it as long as you do not upload a logo (very important detail). So a way to solve your problem could be to have your app create the document and then edit the document adding the data you want. (This is a good solution for personal projects only a few people you know will use)

Comment: You don't need to be verified to put an app in production this is two different things